# Remove commen elements from two lists

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to make a function that, given two lists, removes from both lists the elements they have in commen. I've been breaking My Head over this but I haven't been able to come up with a decent solution.

For example, given:

```
` let a = [1,2,3,4,5] `
` let b = [1,3,5,7,9] `
` f a b `
```

Then f should return something like:

```
` ( [2,4], [7,9] ) `
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking the problem up into smaller pieces? Where exactly are you having trouble? I assume this is homework, but in real life if you encountered this problem you would first consider whether `Set` or some other data structure is more appropriate

Comment: This actually already is broken down of what i actually want. I'm finding it hard as how you need to loop with one list over the other and then return a [Integer] list. I often end up getting a [[Integer]] list where I only removed one element per list. Haven't used any other data structures in Haskell besides lists and tupels, i'll have a look and see of any work better, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean about breaking the problem into smaller pieces for your example: you might define the following functions: `unionLists :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]` (this returns the elements in common between two lists), `delete :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]` (which returns a list with the element you passed as the first parameter removed). Then if you have trouble defining `unionLists` in one go, you might break that down further into `elem :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool` and `filter`, or perhaps `merge` and `sort` if you're feeling clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the lists with with the predicate `not.flip (elem)`:

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
f a b = (filter (not.flip (elem) b) a,filter (not.flip(elem) a) b)
```

If we import `Data.Foldable`, we can use `nonElem` to simplify this a bit further:

```
f a b = (filter (`notElem` b) a,filter (`notElem` a) b)
```

Comment: `Data.Foldable.notElem` and sections make this a bit cleaner: ``(`notElem` b)`` vs. `not . flip elem b`.

Comment: What exactly does flip do? According to hoogle its type is ` (a→ b → c) → (b → a →c) ` would ` (not.flip (elem) b) ` then not be the same as  ` ( not . b (elem)) ` ?

Comment: @Henk No, `flip` flips the arguments of a function. So, for instance, `flip elem x y` is the same as `elem y x`.